# Мой класс не проходит тест. Гляньте, что не так?

Tags: python, ооп

Условие задачи

Класс Elevator – это чертёж лифта. Объект класса Elevator – это созданный по чертежу лифт. Создавая объект класса, вы устанавливаете лифт в доме, указывая количество этажей в доме и текущий этаж, на котором остановился лифт

Если вы не указываете количество этажей и текущий этаж, то по умолчанию лифт устанавливается в доме из 5 этажей и останавливается на 3 этаже

```
Failed test #2 of 6

You answer was: 

Лифт поднимается на 8 этаж
Лифт поднимается на 9 этаж
Лифт опускается на 8 этаж
Лифт опускается на 7 этаж
Лифт опускается на 6 этаж

Correct answer was: 

Лифт не может подняться выше
Лифт не может подняться выше
Лифт опускается на 6 этаж
Лифт опускается на 5 этаж
Лифт опускается на 4 этаж
```

```
class Elevator:
  def __init__( self, количество_этажей_в_доме = 5, текущий_этаж = 3 ) :
    self.количество_этажей_в_доме = количество_этажей_в_доме
    self.текущий_этаж = текущий_этаж
  def up( self ) :
    if self.текущий_этаж == self.количество_этажей_в_доме :
      print( 'Лифт не может подняться выше' )
    else :
      self.текущий_этаж = self.текущий_этаж + 1 
      print( 'Лифт поднимается на ' + str( self.текущий_этаж ) + ' этаж' )
  def down( self ) :
    if self.текущий_этаж == 1 :
      print( 'Лифт не может опуститься ниже' )
    else :
      self.текущий_этаж = self.текущий_этаж - 1 
      print( 'Лифт опускается на ' + str( self.текущий_этаж ) + ' этаж' )
```

От Вас требуется написать только класс Elevator

Для упрощения задачи предполагаем, что минимальный этаж всегда первый. Точно так же не нужно проверять при создании лифта, что текущий этаж больше, чем количество этажей в доме

Comment: Ну всё понятно, степики как всегда накосячили. "Arsenii Hlazov
3 месяца назад
Условие: "Точно так же не нужно проверять при создании лифта, что текущий этаж больше, чем количество этажей в доме." Второй тест: "5 7", т.е. в доме пять этажей, лифт на седьмом. Иначе как издевательством я это назвать не могу."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, оказывается, всё было правильно, но на степике неверно дали вводную информацию. Курс называется "Web-фреймворк Flask: введение" и там вот такая кривая попалась задача. Всем спасибо

```
class Elevator :
  def __init__( self, количество_этажей_в_доме = 5, текущий_этаж = 3 ) :
    if текущий_этаж > количество_этажей_в_доме :
      количество_этажей_в_доме = текущий_этаж  
    self.количество_этажей_в_доме = количество_этажей_в_доме
    self.текущий_этаж = текущий_этаж
    
      
  def up( self ) :
    if self.текущий_этаж == self.количество_этажей_в_доме :
      print( 'Лифт не может подняться выше' )
    else :
      self.текущий_этаж = self.текущий_этаж + 1 
      print( 'Лифт поднимается на ' + str( self.текущий_этаж ) + ' этаж' )
  def down( self ) :
    if self.текущий_этаж < 2 :
      print( 'Лифт не может опуститься ниже' )
    else :
      self.текущий_этаж = self.текущий_этаж - 1 
      print( 'Лифт опускается на ' + str( self.текущий_этаж ) + ' этаж' )
```